# Wordpress scripts not loading correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a static html theme I am trying to convert into a WorsPress theme. I have some troubles loading the scripts.

The scripts are being loaded, but they don't work for some reason.

I can see in my source code that jquery is being loaded:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='url/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='url/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

So in my template folder I have a folder "assets" in this folder I have my scripts in the "js" folder. This is how I load my scripts into the setup.php of my theme.

```
/**
 * Theme assets
 */
function assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, null);

  if (is_single() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
  }

  //header scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/backstretch.js', ['jquery'], null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', ['jquery'], null, false);

  //footer scripts    
    wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', ['jquery'], null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\assets', 100);
```

So in my main.js I get an error in my console and it says

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function (on the $(document).ready line)

I have no idea what's causing this error, since the scripts are being loaded.

Comment: Have you added reference to jquery?

Comment: I am not sure. I thought I read somewhere that it happens automatically?

Comment: inspect the rendered source to check if you have reference to jquery. If not, then add it.

Comment: @BikashSinghMaharjan see edits OP

Comment: check the order of scripts loaded on you page;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I've done this several times, everything looks normal jQuery first then my plugins & bootstrap then my main.js

Comment: May you share live url; if you can;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I can't I am working locally

Comment: One more thing id $(document).ready line before jquery or after jquery script line; ?

Comment: What do you mean? The $(document).ready is in my main.js file and it's being loaded after jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Use this:

in your main.js change

```
$(document).ready
```

to this

```
jQuery(document).ready
```

Also please change all $ to jQuery in your main.js

The tricky thing is this particular copy of jQuery is in compatibility mode by default. That means that the typical '$' shortcut for jQuery doesn't work, so it doesn't conflict with any other JavaScript libraries that use the dollar sign also, like MooTools or Prototype.

Many plugin authors and theme developers are aware of this, and they use 'jQuery' instead of '$' to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

As in the header scripts you are already loading jQuery on the page, then you you don't have to load jQuery this way `[jQuery]` but `array('jquery')` and  it is not required everytime, update to this:

```
wp_register_script('backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/backstretch.js', ['jquery'], null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('backstretch');
    wp_register_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', ['jquery'], null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded');
```

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work, gives same error unfortunately

Comment: I changed it as you suggested but it doesn't work :( Same error

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try this :

```
wp_register_script('backstretch', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/backstretch.js', ['jquery'], null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('backstretch');
    wp_register_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', ['jquery'], null, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded');
```

Comment: I've tried this and the error goes away but I don't think the scripts work